# How can I make webpack compile styles before other entries?

Tags: typescript, webpack, postcss

I want to use a PostCSS plugin that gives me type safety for classnames ([postcss-ts-classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-ts-classnames)). It generates a `.d.ts` file with classNames, as a postcss-plugin. I want to use this to make sure that the JS and CSS say in sync, and we don't keep old classnames around. The current setup works, but only *after* the first build. I'd like to force webpack to compile the CSS *first*, so the `.d.ts` file is always present during the TypeScript compilation.

Ideally I'd like to say to webpack "hey, compiling this will produce a file as byproduct, and another compilation depends on this byproduct".

###### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ['./index.ts', './index.css'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "postcss-loader"
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

###### postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-ts-classnames")({
            dest: "classnames.d.ts",
        }),
    ]
}
```

I don't think the css/ts matter that much, but I put a full (non)-working sample on https://gist.github.com/marijnvdwerf/f44143b6c4cdc7d5c42120bb9eb24744.

Comment: Check if you can leverage something from [this](https://www.viget.com/articles/run-multiple-webpack-configs-sequentially/).

Comment: [before-build-webpack](https://github.com/artemdudkin/before-build-webpack)...

Comment: [Exporting Multiple Configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) from webpack...